# DNS Ubuntu 20.04: host, dig, nslookup works - browser, curl, ping does not

Tags: networking, dns

After a restart I face serious issues with resolving dns on my Ubuntu 20.04. As written,

1. host, dig and nslookup can resolve domain names to IPs e.g.
   `dig @8.8.8.8 google.com dig @8.8.8.8 google.com +tcp`
2. I can ping the outside world using the IP
3. other devices on same wifi work fine
   However, the browser (ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED), services such as curl (Could not resolve host: [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)) or ping an domain do not work.

I changed from local router DNS to 8.8.8.8 (did not change anything) and tried out some other things I found here but without any success for 8+ hours. I had VPNs installed (no nordvpn, just uni), deleted everything I could find with no change...

What is the difference between DNS request from browsers and these tools? The A, AAAA, NX from dig all seems fine. It makes absolutely no sense to me.

Comment: "Does not work" is not a sufficient problem description. Please provide actual commands and results.

Comment: Thanks for your generic answer. Usually I agree. In this case it does not make the problem more specific. It is known how a ping command looks like. Does work = looks up an IP for an address. not= it does not, e.g. browser shows ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED.

Comment: In the topic you're writing ping won't work. In the text you're writing you are able 'to ping the world' ... It is important, because some services are running via UDP, others via TCP. And I think haven't removed your VPN complete. try `dig @8.8.8.8 google.com` vs. `dig @8.8.8.8 google.com +tcp`, I'll expect the second won't work, as you may found out, because it is using TCP instead of UDP. (ping is ICMP, something different).

Comment: Precise commands and exact error messages matter. Without them it is too tedious for me to guess what is going on.

Comment: Ping IP works. Ping to domain shows name or service not known. Thanks for the idea @LupusE. Both of the dig give back an IP! I would love to copy the output but I have to write from my phone which takes forever. Happy to do so if important. Are there other ways to check/fix icmp?

Comment: Have you rebooted your system?  What do you see for `sudo ip route list && sudo ip -4 addr list` (to make sure ypu have an internet link and not some odd screwy route)

Comment: Yes, I have done multiple reboots. Found a way to copy outputs via bluetooth...
`default via 192.168.xxx.1 dev wlp0s20f3 proto dhcp metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp0s20f3 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.xxx.0/24 dev wlp0s20f3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.xxx.60 metric 600 
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever`

Comment: sorry I had to split in to
`3: wlp0s20f3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 192.168.xxx.60/24 brd 192.168.xxx.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp0s20f3
       valid_lft 863874sec preferred_lft 863874sec`

Comment: As an experiment, I added archive.ubuntu.com and other sites to /etc/hosts. I can open these sites in the browser and install package (reinstalled resolvconf) without problems... So def DNS. I also stopped a vpnxxx service that was running and I managed to locate it to cisco anyconnect which is officially uninstalled. Installed and uninstalled it again. service is gone however problem not solved...

Comment: Please take a look into the file `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. there should be something like `hosts:          files dns`. Just another guess into the blue this issue would not match with your described situation. but when you are able to install packages, `wireshark` will help to see what is 'on the line' .. if the request goes out, bot won't come back, maybe the MTU is messed up (related to the VPN, `ip link list` should help to see the configured value)? If the request wasn't get out, next packet would be `strace`, to see where the browser does get his domain information.

Comment: AAAAARGH! Back to DNS-life! Not sure what did the trick in the end. I reinstalled resolv, restart no change. Then installed bind9 and in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` I added "dns" to the "hosts: files" line. Restartet. And it worked. Thanks a ton to everyone that helped.

Answer (score 0):

After the discussion, I'll try to come with an explanation. Main Point: There was a VPN Client installed, and removed. Name resolving stopped working.

`dig @8.8.8.8 google.com` asks the server 8.8.8.8 what IP is assigned to google.com.
`dig google.com` shouldn't have worked.

Linux does look into the file `/etc/nsswitch.conf` how to resolve names to IP.
`hosts: files` means it will look into the **/etc/hosts**, done.
`hosts: files dns` means it will look into the **/etc/hosts**, then resolve via **resolveconf** (or more `network-manager`, today).

It could be a little more complex:
`hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname`

In case you've installed the VPN via dpkg (a .deb package with `dpkg -i` or using `apt`), there is a good chance the original `/etc/nsswitch.conf` is still in /etc, named something like `/etc/nsswitch.dpkg-old`.

If you need the original file, you'll always can download it by searching on https://packages.ubuntu.com/ for content: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=nsswitch.conf

- Download the .deb file (in this case **libc-bin** or **glibc-source** should be nearly the same)
- extract it (it's just an archive, `ar -x <filename>.deb`)
- compare the original with yours
- fix the needed lines

I am intentionally left out `network-manager` in depth or `netplan.io`.